# Access to non-sandboxed disk in Chrome Native Client

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

Chrome Native Client provides [File IO API](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/coding/FileIO) to access sandboxed local disk. But is it possible to access non-sandboxed disk, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can launch chrome with `--no-sandbox` command-line flag and use the following environment variable:

```
set NACL_DANGEROUS_ENABLE_FILE_ACCESS=1
```

to enable direct file access. See this blog [post](http://mainroach.blogspot.ru/2012/02/nacl-dangerous-file-io.html) for details.

This mode is created for debugging purposes, it will never be enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to directly access non-sandboxed local disk from the browser. (If it were, there wouldn't be much point in having the sandbox, right?) You can use HTML/JS to have the user choose a file and pass it to the nacl module (see http://mainroach.blogspot.com/2012/07/native-client-and-loading-user-chosen.html).